# System does not boot on the first try with new GPU

Tags: boot, gpu

I seem to have a little problem with my PC. I recently changed my video card to a Gigabyte GTX680 Windforce 5x from a POV GTX580 and i seem to get some kind of boot error ( 1 long beep and 3 short beeps ) that my motherboard signals as a VGA error.

I should add that my graphic card starts with 100% fan speed ( sounds like a Jet ready to take off ) after that it does a couple of seconds than full throttle again.

Just upgraded my bios to the most recent version ( that is not a beta ) and it seems that it needs a lot of boots to actually start ( between 5 and 20 boots to actually start ).

I managed to do some benchmarks and everything that can be run on the GPU, seems to be working perfectly ( also played GW2 and DOTA2 both working fine ). Also I used another GPU on my motherboard with the same system and used mine on another computer, both seemed to work perfectly.

PC specs:

Motherboard: Asus Crosshair IV formula

PSU: Corsair 650W 80+

Video: Gigabyte GTX680 Windforce 5x

CPU: AMD 1090T 6 cores 3.2/3.6 GHz

RAM: Corsair 8 GB 1600 9CL

CPU Cooler: Noctua NH-D14

Tower: Cooler Master HAF 912 Plus ( with all the fans installed ).

```
                                           Thank you in advance, please help
```

Comment: Have you confirmed the new video card is not defective?

Comment: yes, and i also tried it on another PC, worked fine

Comment: so nobody knows what is happening with my pc ? maybe some ideas of what should i do ?